# instance syntax to search for all child cases of a parent in CommCare

Tags: commcare

I have an app that uses a 'household' parent case and 'member' child case. Within the 'member' visit form I want to be able to search for the # of other child cases indexed to that parent who meet a certain criteria:

In english: How many other child cases are indexed to this patient with the property mm_is_in_tb_treatment = 'yes'?

Instance path:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_type='household']/ ...
```

and then I'm not sure how to specify this 'member' case's 'household', then filter for child cases of this household, then filter for

```
/mm_is_in_tb_treatment = 'yes'
```

Once I get the instance syntax correct, what is the output? I need the total # cases that meet that criteria.

Comment: Hi @Sathya, while these questions look programming oriented, these are actually just snippets of formula that go into text boxes on a web application. They are very similar to Excel formulas and are for advanced users. You can see previous discussion here: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103045/filtering-an-instance-by-a-case-property-in-my-commcare-app

Comment: @BenRudolph thanks for clearing that up, will reopen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming in this case that you've loaded a the `member` case into your form, and that you can load the member case ID id into

```
/data/member_id
```

What you want to get is:

The count of all `member` cases which are children of this case's parent, for which the member case has the property `mm_is_in_tb_treatment = 'yes'`

For now we can create a new hidden value to store the parent household's case ID, since it'll make understanding the full query below easier.

New hidden value: `/data/parent_id`:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_id = /data/member_id]/index/parent
```

All cases which are children of that parent would be referenced as:

```
instance('casedb')/casedb/case[index/parent = /data/parent_id]
```

You can now add your new filter directly to the end of that statement and introduce the count

```
count(instance('casedb')/casedb/case[index/parent = /data/parent_id][mm_is_in_tb_treatment = 'yes']
```

If you wanted, you could further specify that you (for safety) only want to include children that are `member` cases and which are open. You can also collapse back the parent ID reference if you want a one-line expression:

```
count(instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_type='member'][@status='open'][index/parent = instance('casedb')/casedb/case[@case_id = /data/member_id]/index/parent][mm_is_in_tb_treatment = 'yes']
```